# Java Spring web client using JSON requests

Tags: java, json, spring

I am developing a Java web server (using spring) that would receive a JSON response from a website. I am new to Spring and having a hard time figuring out how to handle json response in Spring? How could I receive and send a JSON response back? Any examples or links that can be shared is appreciated.

Comment: Read about Spring MVC. Spring provides producers and consumers for JSON/XML. You really don't have to do much in terms of parsing or generating request response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly go through this link and let me know if you still can't get it
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/
The @ResponseBody is the key to your solution

Comment: Thank you that was helpful. However , it only shows JSON output. I am trying to get JSON Input also

Comment: For getting JSON input you need to lookup GSON which converts Java collections to JSON. Do try to search and if you are so having trouble do let me know

Comment: Kindly let me know if the your concern has been resolved else kindly accept the answer and close the question